# How can one bind HashTable keys to a ListBox in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, listbox, hashtable

I'm helping a friend port some code that I have written in Java to Visual Basic.NET. VB.NET is not my language of choose, so I am entirely new to it's quirks. How can I display keys from a HashTable in a ListBox?

Thanks in advance,

Sean W.

Comment: Small notice, do **not** use `Hashtable`. That class is deprecated. Only use the collection classes from the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace. The equivalent of `Hashtable` is called `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   For Each key As Object In myHashTable.Keys
       ListBox1.Items.Add(key.ToString)
   Next
```

or

```
   Dim enumerator As IDictionaryEnumerator = myHashTable.GetEnumerator()
   While enumerator.MoveNext
       ListBox1.Items.Add(enumerator.Key)
   End While
```

But you should use generic dictionaries instead that are type safe and therefore faster and less errorphrone.

```
    Dim myDictionary As New Dictionary(Of Int32, String)
    For i As Int32 = 1 To 1000
        myDictionary.Add(i, i & ". Entry")
    Next
    For Each key As String In myDictionary.Keys
        ListBox1.Add(key)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.keys.aspx) property on your `Hashtable` should be bindable directly to the [`Datasource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource.aspx) property on your `Listbox`